# Service Account is not appearing on the Google Play API Access

Tags: android, google-play-console, service-accounts

to test the Google Play Billing developers have requested me the Google Service Account.
I did go to Google Play Console -> Account -> API and have already linked the "Google Play Android Developer" project there. Then I went to the link in the Service Account and created one on the cloud platform.
However, that service account is not appearing in the Service Accounts section of the Google Play Console, and it was already 4 days passed.

Any suggestion you have on how to troubleshoot that?

For your kind support many thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Dmitry